# Assign dictionary value from another dictionary value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get lost in the peace of code. I have two dictionaries as below, and I want to replace the values of vigitables dictionary by the values of the fruits dictionary.

```
fruits = {'Apples':2,'Oranges':4,'Bananas':6}

vigitables = {'Tomatos':3,'Potatos':5,'Onions':7}
```

i tried this

```
for k in vigitables.keys():

vigitables[k] = fruits.values()
```

but it gave me None.

the expecting output

```
vigitables = {'Tomatos':2,'Potatos':4,'Onions':6}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `dict(zip(...))` command:

```
print(dict(zip(vigitables.keys(), fruits.values())))
```

For a loop command:

```
d = {}
for x, y in zip(vigitables.keys(), fruits.values()):
    d.update({x: y})
```

For loop solution without `zip`:

```
d = {}
keys = list(vigitables.keys())
values = list(fruits.values())
for i in range(len(keys)):
    d.update({keys[i]: values[i]})
```

They all output:

```
{'Tomatos': 2, 'Potatos': 4, 'Onions': 6}
```

Comment: I would like to know how to do it using for loop?

Comment: how to do it using for loop without zip ??

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answer, but more concise. When you use `vigitables`, you take only its keys.

```
dict(zip(vigitables, fruits.values()))
```

**Example**:

```
fruits = {'Apples':2,'Oranges':4,'Bananas':6}

vigitables = {'Tomatos':3,'Potatos':5,'Onions':7}  
print(dict(zip(vigitables, fruits.values())))

# {'Tomatos': 2, 'Potatos': 4, 'Onions': 6}
```

`zip()` creates a tuple of key and value from the two dictionaries and a `dict()` on it creates dictionary.